# Auth0 on iOS: Error Domain=com.auth0 Can't find connection name to use for authentication

Tags: ios, swift, auth0

I am receiving this error when trying to connect with Auth0 iOS SDK:

> Error Domain=com.auth0 Code=18 "Authentication failed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication failed,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Can't find connection name to use for
>   authentication}

Here is my code:

```
   let client : A0APIClient =  A0Lock.sharedLock().apiClient()
    client.signUpWithEmail(emailTextField.text!,
                           password: passwordTextField.text!,
                           loginOnSuccess: true,
                           parameters: nil,
                           success: { (profile: A0UserProfile?, tokenInfo: A0Token?) in

                          })
    { (NSError) in
        print(NSError)
    }
```

I'm assuming I have to set the connection inside the parameters variable, but how do I do that? I couldn't find any reference code in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
let parameters = A0AuthParameters(dictionary: [A0ParameterConnection : "Username-Password-Authentication"])
```